# Button is moved out of the visible content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've got a problem with my CSS styling. I've got some example headers with the possibility to add some header bookmarks with help of the "PLUS" button. You can see the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-feather-wjxfuu?file=/src/App.js or:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    const newItem = { id: list.length, name: `Item ${list.length + 1}` };
    setList([...list, newItem]);
  };

  const handleRemoveItem = (index) => {
    setList(list.filter((item) => index !== item.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "400px",
          height: "50px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          gap: "8px",
          overflow: "hidden",
          padding: "8px",
          border: "1px solid red"
        }}
      >
        {list.map((item, i) => (
          <div
            key={i}
            style={{
              border: "1px solid blue",
              borderRadius: "5px",
              padding: "4px",
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              color: "white",
              cursor: "pointer",
              overflow: " hidden",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis"
            }}
            onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(i)}
          >
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={handleAddItem}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is, that when I add some number of the bookmarks, then in some cases the "PLUS" button starts to overflow the div container(header) as you can see in the GIF.

[image]

I want the button not to overflow the content.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the body of the question itself, otherwise any changes to your link may stop the question being useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi***, Simply make the button directly in the div classed app `<div className="App">`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    const newItem = { id: list.length, name: `Item ${list.length + 1}` };
    setList([...list, newItem]);
  };

  const handleRemoveItem = (index) => {
    setList(list.filter((item) => index !== item.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "400px",
          height: "50px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          gap: "8px",
          overflow: "hidden",
          padding: "8px",
          border: "1px solid red"
        }}
      >
        {list.map((item, i) => (
          <div
            key={i}
            style={{
              border: "1px solid blue",
              borderRadius: "5px",
              padding: "4px",
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              color: "white",
              cursor: "pointer",
              overflow: " hidden",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis"
            }}
            onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(i)}
          >
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `div` to keep all your items separate from your button

You can try [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-monad-61r2rd?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    const newItem = { id: list.length, name: `Item ${list.length + 1}` };
    setList([...list, newItem]);
  };

  const handleRemoveItem = (index) => {
    setList(list.filter((item) => index !== item.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "400px",
          height: "50px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          gap: "8px",
          overflow: "hidden",
          padding: "8px",
          border: "1px solid red"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            height: "50px",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            gap: "8px",
            overflow: "hidden"
          }}
        >
          {list.map((item, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
              style={{
                border: "1px solid blue",
                borderRadius: "5px",
                padding: "4px",
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                color: "white",
                cursor: "pointer",
                overflow: " hidden",
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                textOverflow: "ellipsis"
              }}
              onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(i)}
            >
              {item.name}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleAddItem}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```